# I can not stop a Runnable using Handler in JAVA

Tags: java, android, callback, android-handler

I am trying to build a stopwatch and i have a button named start which starts the counting, after it starts the name of the button changes to stop and when i press stop i want to pause the counting, but when i am trying to run `newHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);`the program continues counting, on the reset button this method works.

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button start_button, reset_button;
    TextView time_view;
    long start_time = 0, time_in_miliseconds = 0, update_time = 0, prev_time = 0;
    final Handler newHandler = new Handler();

    Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
        private boolean isActive;
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(isActive)
            {
                prev_time += time_in_miliseconds;
                newHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                start_button.setText("Start");
                //time_view.setText(""+save_hour+":"+String.format("%2d",save_min)+":"+String.format("%2d",save_sec)+"."+String.format("%3d",save_centisec));
            }
            else
            {
                time_in_miliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start_time;
                update_time = time_in_miliseconds + prev_time;
                int sec = (int) (update_time / 1000);
                int min = sec / 60;
                int hour = (int) sec / 3600;
                sec %= 60;
                int centisec = (int) (update_time / 10) % 100;
                time_view.setText(""+hour+":"+String.format("%2d",min)+":"+String.format("%2d",sec)+"."+String.format("%3d",centisec));
                newHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);
            }
            isActive = !isActive;
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        start_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        reset_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset_button);
        time_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_view);

        start_button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            start_time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            start_button.setText("Stop");
            newHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread,0);
        });

        reset_button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            // Here the Runnable is stopped
            newHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            start_time = 0;
            prev_time = 0;
            time_view.setText("0:0:0.0");
            start_button.setText("Start");
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove all conditions blocks where you are checking `start_button.isPressed()`, it doesn't work. You can use additional flag `isRunning` to indicate whether the clock is running or not:

```
private boolean isRunning;

start_button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (isRunning) {
            newHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            start_button.setText("Start");
        } else {
            start_time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            start_button.setText("Stop");
            newHandler.post(updateTimerThread);
        }
        isRunning = !isRunning;
    });
```

Comment: I updated the code with your solution but it's still not working, it's just stopping the clock right after is started. You can see my updated code in the original question

Comment: please, pay attention that my code is in `start_button.setOnClickListener` block, not in `updateTimerThread` runnable like in your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Your timer needs some state. You could do something like this (add 'boolean isActive'):

```
        Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
            boolean isActive = true;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isActive) {
                    time_in_miliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start_time;
                    update_time = time_in_miliseconds + prev_time;
                    // ...
                }
                if (start_button.isPressed()) {
                    isActive = !isActive;
                    // Do some other stuff
                }
            }
        };
```

Or maybe use the State Pattern.